# C program. Taking top number from input file, creating 2d array, then reading grid from file

Tags: c

Sorry if this question has been askked I've been looking on this site for a couple hours and haven't seen anything yet.

So I'm reading an input file that looks like this. The top line being an 8x8 2d array, then the remaining lines the grid I have to sort through. Basically I'm replacing each * with a  letter +1, so a,b,c...etc but that's not my question.

```
8   <---- The size of the array 8X8
**......       
**..*..*
..**.**.
..**..*.
.*..*..*
..**.**.
..**.**.
.*..*..*
```

my question is, how can I read just the top line of the input file to find the size of the array then store that as the row and columns of my array, then read the remainder of the file (the grid) and store the characters into the rows and columns of the array?

This is what I have so far.

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#define N 9

void blobchecker(char[][N]);

main()
{
    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen("blobfile.txt", "r");
    if ((fp = fopen("blobfile.txt", "r")) == NULL) 
        printf("File not read \n");

    int c;
    char myarray[N][N];
    int i, j;

    fscanf(fp, "%d", &c);
    fclose(fp);
    fp = fopen("blobfile.txt", "r");
    for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
        for (j = 0; j < N; j++)
            fscanf(fp, "%c", &myarray[i][j]);

    for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
        for (j = 0; j < N; j++)
            printf("%c", myarray[i][j]);

    printf("\n Now checking for blobs \n");

    // blobchecker(myarray);

    fclose(fp);
}
```

Comment: An unrelated note, but if you fail to open the file, would that not be a fatal error? You can't really continue after that, especially not continue to try and read from the file. Also, why are you closing and reopening the file? That will lead to your code being out of step with the data in the file as the first character you will read in the loops is the array size. You also don't handle the newlines.

Comment: As for your problem, define `myarray` *after* you read the size. C supports [variable-length arrays](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
int c;
char** myarray;
int i;
fscanf(fp, "%d", &c);
myarray = malloc(c*sizeof(char*));
for (i=0; i<c; i++)
    myarray[i] = malloc(c);
```

And don't forget to free the allocated memory at a  later point in the execution of your program:

```
for (i=0; i<c; i++)
    free(myarray[i]);
free(myarray);
```

Comment: To avoid trouble caused by newline character, add space before `%c`: `fscanf(fp, " %c", &myarray[i][j]);`

Comment: Any reason why you recommend the OP not to use a 2D array? There is nothing in the code indicating that he has any use of this lookup table thing you posted.

Comment: @Lundin: Hi. Again - same issue as last time... How would you recommend to implement that using dynamic allocation (and allowing the usage of `[][]` of course)?

Comment: @barakmanos I wrote an edit to my answer which includes an example of how to allocate a 2D array and remain compatible with 1980s legacy compilers like Visual Studio.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution without using heap allocated memory. Note: This solution works only with the C99 standard and onward versions.

```
int main()
{
    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen("blobfile.txt", "r");
    if ((fp = fopen("blobfile.txt", "r")) == NULL) {
        printf("File not read \n");
        return 1; // end the program when the file can't be opened
    }

    int c;
    int i, j;

    fscanf(fp, "%d", &c);

    char myarray[c][c]; // variable length array using the read size

    for (i = 0; i < c; i++) // use c as upper limit
        for (j = 0; j < c; j++)
            fscanf(fp, " %c", &myarray[i][j]);

    for (i = 0; i < c; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < c; j++)
            printf("%c", myarray[i][j]);
        printf("\n");
    }
    printf("\n Now checking for blobs \n");

    //blobchecker(myarray);

    fclose(fp);

}
```

Your problem was opening and reopening the file once you've read the array size.
By opening the file again you reset the 'cursor' (*stream position indicator*) to the beginning of the file. So the first charactar you've read was the size of your array.

Comment: While VLAs (variable-length arrays) are supported in C99 onward, the question is tagged *c* (in other words, your suggested code will not necessarily compile).

Comment: @barakmanos I edited the answer to mark it's a C99 solutiion.

Comment: @muXXmit2X There's no need for that, your answer was fine as it was, barak manos is just confused about the C tag usage. According to the C tag wiki, it is assumed that all questions in the C tag uses the current ISO standard, which is at this point 9899:2011. If the OP is interested in legacy versions of C, they need to explicitly tag their question K&R, C90 or C99.

Comment: @Lundin Yes I know. I already read this in your other comments. But it is still correct. The solution will not work with older standards so I will keep the note ;)

Comment: Yes, but this is really the best answer to the question, there is no obvious need for dynamic allocation to begin with. My own answer was merely written to counter-teach the recommendations of the other answers here.

Answer (score 1):

This has been pretty much answered, but couple of additional notes: It might be easier to use `fscanf(fp,"%s", myarray[i][])`. The `fscanf` will take care of the newline chararter, and this way you can assign a whole string to a desired array in 2d matrix. Makes reading and handling way easier and you can still refer to a specific member of an array using both of his indexes. Make sure to allocate the memory correctly and take care: fscanf which takes care of the `\n` will add it to your string! But overall it's a simpler solution. 
Also, as it has been said, avoid closing and reopening the file. If you do this, you're losing an offset pointer so you're basically reading a file all over again from the top, which is neither necessary or needed.

Comment: `fscanf(fp,"%s", myarray[i][])` won't compile

Comment: "_`fscanf` which takes care of the `\n` will add it to your string_" `%s` will never scan and store a whitespace character.

Answer (score 0):

Dynamically allocate memory using `malloc` and `free` it after its use.

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
/* `#define N 9` Not needed */

void blobchecker(char**); /* Note the change here */

int main(void) /* Always use a standard signature of main */
{

    /* Indent your code properly always */

    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen("blobfile.txt", "r");
    if ((fp = fopen("blobfile.txt", "r")) == NULL) 
    {
        /* `printf("File not read \n");` Better to print in stderr */
        fputs("Failed to open file 'blobfile.txt'", stderr);
        return EXIT_FAILURE; /* Exit the program (main) */
    }


    int c;
    /* char myarray[N][N]; */
    char **myarray; /* Note the change here */
    int i, j;

    fscanf(fp, "%d", &c);

    /*
    `fclose(fp);`
    `fp = fopen("blobfile.txt", "r");` Don't close and reopen
    */

    myarray = malloc(c * sizeof *myarray); /* Allocate `c` rows */
    if(NULL == myarray) /* If `malloc` failed */
    {
        fputs("Failed to malloc 'myarray'", stderr);
        return EXIT_FAILURE; /* Exit the program (main) */
    }
    for (i = 0; i < c; i++)
    {
        myarray[i] = malloc(c); /* For each row, allocate `c` columns */
        if(NULL == myarray[i]) /* If `malloc` failed */
        {
            for(j = i - 1; j >= 0; j--) /* `free` all previously allocated memory */
                free(myarray[j]);
            free(myarray);
            fputs("Failed to malloc 'myarray[i]'", stderr);
            return EXIT_FAILURE; /* Exit the program (main) */
        }
    }

    for (i = 0; i < c; i++)
        for (j = 0; j < c; j++)
            fscanf(fp, " %c", &myarray[i][j]); /* Space before `%c` gets rid of whitespaces */

    for (i = 0; i < c; i++)
        for (j = 0; j < c; j++)
            printf("%c", myarray[i][j]);

    printf("\n Now checking for blobs \n");

    //blobchecker(myarray);

    fclose(fp);

    /* `free` whatever you've allocated after its use: */

    for (i = 0; i < c; i++)
        free(myarray[i]);
    free(myarray);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS; /* Exit main */

}
```

<sup><sub>WARNING: Untested code</sub></sup>

---

Note that in the above code,each call to `malloc` may allocate memory non-contiguously and this would result in heap fragmentation and reduced efficiency of the program. @Lundin's comments mention more about this.

Comment: Any reason why you recommend the OP not to use a 2D array? There is nothing in the code indicating that he has any use of this lookup table thing you posted.

Comment: @Lundin You mean a VLA, right? Its because they are available only in C99 and above. Also, judging by `#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS`, the OP is using VS and since VS uses C89, it is not supported. Note: I know that there is partial C99 support in the latest versions of VS, but don't know if VLAs are included in this.

Comment: No I mean a 2D array, be it declared as a VLA or something else. If you are using a dinosaur compiler, you have to dynamically allocate your 2D array as a "mangled one", `char* myarray = malloc (c*c);`. Still, that is a true 2D array. It is not segmented all over the heap and code using it will optimize well, instead of poorly.

Comment: Does 'dinosaur compiler' refer to compilers that `malloc` memory in random positions? Yes. I agree that contiguous allocation can result in less fragmentation resulting in better performance, but 1) OP seems to be a begineer 2) For a small program, it won't really matter. However, For large programs going to be deployed to the public, this might matter. I'll edit my answer to reflect that.

Answer (score 0):

If the dimension is only known in run-time, you can use a VLA:

```
int c;
fscanf(fp, "%d", &c);

char myarray[c][c];

for (i = 0; i < c; i++)
    for (j = 0; j < c; j++)
        fscanf(fp, "%c", &myarray[i][j]);
```

If the amount of memory to read is wast, it might be better to allocate the 2D array dynamically, to ensure that the memory ends up on the heap:

```
char (*myarray)[c] = malloc( sizeof(char[c][c]) );
...
free(myarray);
```

There should never be any need of obscure `char**`-based look-up tables in your case. All they will do is to segment your array all over the heap and make your program slower.

---

**EDIT**

If you need to be backwards-compatible with the 27 years old, obsolete C89 standard, you could write portable code like this:

```
#ifndef __STDC_VERSION__
  #define OLD_JUNK
#elif __STDC_VERSION__ < 199901L
  #define OLD_JUNK
#endif

#ifdef OLD_JUNK
  #define get_item(arr, x, y) (arr [(x) * (y)] )
#else
  #define get_item(arr, x, y) (arr[x][y])
#endif

int c;
fscanf(fp, "%d", &c);

#ifdef OLD_JUNK
  char* myarray = malloc(c * c);
#else
  char (*myarray)[c] = malloc ( sizeof(char[c][c]) );
#endif

int i, j;
for (i = 0; i < c; i++)
    for (j = 0; j < c; j++)
        fscanf(fp, "%c", &get_item(myarray,i,j) );

free(myarray);
```

I would however strongly recommend to upgrade to a compiler which is not using 1980s technology. Then you would not have to write ugly solutions like this.

Comment: While VLAs (variable-length arrays) are supported in C99 onward, the question is tagged *c* (in other words, your suggested code will not necessarily compile).

Comment: @barakmanos [C tag wiki, tag usage:](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/c/info) "Unless the question explicitly mentions which version of the C standard that is used, it is assumed that the current version is used." To my understanding, this is how programming language tags work on SO in general.

Comment: @barakmanos Still, that is not an excuse to use a fragmented look-up thing instead of a real 2D array. In C90 you would write `char* myarray = malloc (c*c);` and then access that 2D array as `myarray[i * j]`.

Comment: It is debatable whether one can correctly refer to such data structure as a 2D array. IMO, it is a 1D array, but I suppose that it's a matter of terminology.

Comment: @barakmanos All that matters in practice, is that it is allocated in adjacent memory, so you can treat it as an array. For any real array in C, you can use functions like `memcpy, strcpy, memcmp` etc. And you can fread/fwrite it as one single chunk of memory, rather than byte-by-byte.

Comment: Based on what part in the question do you determine that it matters more than the ability to use a 2D array syntax in the code (e.g., `[i][j]`)? Although I agree on the advantages of contiguous memory allocation in general, the OP has not mentioned any of those functions as part of the question requirements.

Comment: @barakmanos Unless it wasn't already obvious, my whole reason for bringing this up is that you shouldn't be teaching beginners to use the wide-spread, but none-the-less blatantly incorrect, pointer-to-pointer look-up table method. It will lead to heap fragmentation, it will lead to poorly optimized code (particularly, poorly optimized data cache use), it will lead to problems and bugs when attempting to treat the memory as adjacent. All of these problems for no gain whatsoever.

Comment: I agree in general, but sometimes beginners are better off learning one thing at a time. And if we're speaking in the context of OP being a  beginner (a reasonable assumption here), then I think that your answer, as good as it may be in terms of covering all aspects, might be a little too detailed for the OP to "absorb" (in particularly, everything that comes after the VLA suggestion).